# Problema de texto cortado ao criar arquivo texto

Tags: php, string, fopen

Preciso criar um arquivo que contem código PHP. Esse código vem de uma string como `"<?php class foo{ } ?>"` porém quando dou um `echo` ela simplesmente corta as palavras reservadas.

Como transformar a string em texto puro sem escapar nenhuma palavra?

Vou criar um arquivo por `fopen`.

Comment: Poste seu código e tente indicar melhor qual é o problema. Que testes você fez.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`htmlentities`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlentities.php):

```
echo htmlentities($suaString);
```

Isso só na hora de exibir (parece que aí está o seu problema). No arquivo texto, sua string deve ser gravada sem escapar nada.

Comment: Certo vou testar hoje a noite e digo o resultado. De qualquer forma obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Criando e ler o Arquivo com [fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) do [php](/questions/tagged/php)

```
//Criando arquivo
$arq = fopen('arquivo.txt', 'a+');

//Gravando tags sem perder o contéudo do texto coloque aspas simples
fwrite($arq, '<?php echo $variavel; >'."\r\n");
fclose($arq);
```

---

```
//Lendo o arquivo
$arq = fopen('arquivo.txt', 'r');
//Pegando o conteudo
$lin = fread($arq, filesize('arquivo.txt'));
//Imprimindo o conteudo
echo  htmlentities($lin);
```

Referências:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Comment: Certo vou testar hoje a noite e digo o resultado. De qualquer forma obrigado!

Comment: @LeandroCurioso você testou ???